# Alternative to iOS's deprecated UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I have an app that I do NOT want to run in the background. There is nothing my app can do in background mode, and allowing it to only adds annoying UI complications.  I want the app to terminate when it is removed from the foreground.

`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` was Apple's method of allowing this before, and it worked perfectly for my use case. However, it is now deprecated and they are rejecting apps with that Info.plist value.

The only alternative I've been able to find is `exit(0)` in an app delegate method, but Apple strongly discourages this, and it appears as a crash.

Is there any other viable alternative?  I simply do not want my app to run in the background, all it does is drain a user's battery unnecessarily.

Comment: If your app isn't doing anything then it can't be draining the battery. It will be suspended, so doing nothing. Relaunching your app from scratch will use more battery than simply resuming it from its suspended state. This is why it is a bad habit to "swipe away" all the apps in the app switcher (as well as it also preventing them from performing any required background tasks)

Comment: I have a similar use case.  My application has a requirement to exit when it goes to the background so that the user has to log in again.  I suppose my alternative it to allow the application to go to the background and put them into the login sequence again when they resume.

Comment: Bump and thirding the question.  Have an app I need DEAD when exiting, no background or suspend of any kind.  UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend worked great for this, and I also don't want to resort to exit(0).

Comment: I you don't explicitly allow "background modes" for your app, your app will do nothing nor draining anything

Comment: Another important use for this flag is that it simply avoids all sorts of possible  and hard to reproduce bugs. Memory leaks, triggering bugs in Apple's own frameworks when in the background for extended periods of time (WKWebView is notorious for this), etc... I'd go a step further and say that terminating an app should actually be the **default** behaviour in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` I check the elapsed time in background an reset my navigation if needed :

- I keep the last time the app did enter in background (`NSUserDefaults` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`)
- When the application did become active again I check the saved time (in `applicationDidBecomeActive`) against a given time threshold.
- I reset my navigation if my threshold is overrun (this allow me to resync my app or re-ask for login after some times, but allowing a quick phone call for exemple)

Since it's an old app here is the objective-c :

**appdelegate.m :**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"APPLIFE : going to sleep ... ");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSDate date] forKey:@"last-background-time"];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"APPLIFE : ... back to front");
    NSDate * bgTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"last-background-time"];

    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastRun = fabs([bgTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    double threshold = 60 * 60 * 24; //in seconds.   

    if (secondsSinceLastRun > threshold) {
        NSLog(@"APPLIFE : Too old, reboot app");
        //[navigationController popToRoot] or whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI, Add this to the App struct:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
```

then add these two classes:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
    options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
  ) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    let sceneConfig = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    sceneConfig.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self // 
    return sceneConfig
  }
```

}

class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
// This will force the app to start fresh each time after two seconds (so the close animation looks clean)
do {
sleep(2)
}
exit(0)
}
}